# Issues capturing from RTSP (Wyze Cam V2) using OpenCV on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, image, opencv, raspberry-pi, rtsp

I am an "advanced beginner" in Python, but a relative newbie with the Raspberry Pi...

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to capture a frame from the RTSP stream from a Wyze Cam V2 and save the image to a file.  My code works - most of the time.  But sometimes it fails for long periods of time.  After much experimentation and trial and error I have determined that it is more likely to fail when the camera is in the dark!  This seems very consistent.

**My Code:**

This is not the code from my actual project - it is the code I have been using to troubleshoot.

```
import cv2
import imageio


class Camera:
    def __init__(self, ipaddress):
        self.ipaddress = ipaddress
        print("About to create VideoStream")
        self.vs = cv2.VideoCapture(ipaddress, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
        self.vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 3)
        if self.vs.isOpened():
            print("Successfully created")
            self.vs.release()
        else:
            print("Unable to create")

    def capture(self):
        self.vs.open(self.ipaddress)
        success, frame = self.vs.read()
        self.vs.release()
        if success:
            print("Capture Success")
            return frame
        else:
            print("Failed to capture")
            print("VideoCapture isOpen is " + str(self.vs.isOpened()))
            return None

    def is_opened(self):
        return self.vs.isOpened()

# In actual code CAMNAME is the camera's name, PASSWORD is the password
# and XXX.XXX.X.XXX is the ip address

camera = Camera("rtsp://CAMNAME:PASSWORD@XXX.XXX.X.XXX/live") 


leave = False

while not leave:
    frame = camera.capture()
    if frame is None:
        print("Frame is none")
        print("VideoCapture isOpen is " + str(camera.is_opened()))
    else:
        print("Successful capture - writing to file")
        frame_color = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        imageio.imwrite("test.jpg", frame_color)
    response = input("Capture again? ")
    if len(response) == 0:
        response = "y"
    if response[0] == 'n':
        leave = True
```

**What I Have Tried:**

- The code works fine when run on Windows 10.  So not directly a problem with the code.  In fact, when the Pi is having trouble capturing, doing it at the same time on Windows works.  So definitely the issue is the Pi interacting with OpenCV or the camera.
- Since I had ++ trouble installing OpenCV:

  - I have tried re-installing it on a fresh install of the OS with PIP (sudo pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.0.25).
  - I tried to build OpenCV from scratch - took 2.5 days and failed miserably - likely I screwed up somewhere in the process, but don't feel like spending another 2 days doing this.
  - Finally I downloaded a Raspbian image with OpenCV pre-compiled (https://medium.com/@aadeshshah/pre-installed-and-pre-configured-raspbian-with-opencv-4-1-0-for-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-b-9c307b9a993a).  All these install methods resulted in the same issues...
- I have tried opening the VideoCapture without specifying cv2.CAP_FFMPEG.  I feel like it was more reliable with this option.
- I have tried leaving out the change in BUFFERSIZE.  I'm not sure this line of code has any effect.

**What I am Using:**

- Raspberry Pi Model B, Rev 2, 512 kb
- Raspbian Stretch - though I have had the same issues with Buster.
- Wyze Cam II "beta" firmware that provides RTSP support.
- Python3
- OpenCV 4.1.0 (cv2.**version**)

**What happens:**

- I have been troubleshooting this intermittent problem for some time, and just today realized it always works with the garage (where the camera is located) is light, and fails when it is dark.  (Which made the late night troubleshooting sessions so frustrating!)
- I have had many problems in the past, but now the issue seems to be that if the garage (where the camera is located) is dark, the VideoCapture object will not be created (.isOpened() == False) or the read() method will return False, None.
- I used to have a problem with read() returning an old image.  I can tell it is old because the camera timestamps the captures.  This is why I am always opening and closing the VideoCapture - I would rather it not return an image than return the wrong/old image.
- In the past, with slightly different settings, I would get warnings on the screen either during the creation of the VideoCapture object, or during the read() command.  These are usually along the lines of "[h264 @ 0x1ea1780] error while decoding MB 78 67, bytestream -15".  I have gotten different warnings but I don't have examples right now.  If I get a warning, I often get a bad image.
- I have also gotten images that are distorted - that bottom of the image (sometimes a few lines, sometimes more than half of the image) looks like it it is the same line of data over and over.

Comment: IP cameras have different set up options inside and I think you can reach them via on a browser. The options like: day time settings, durations, autofocus etc. But you are saying problem only occurs on raspberry pi. Does it work for a while then crashes? This may seem like cpu difference instead of operating system difference. Also you mentioned many problems, it can be difficult to help and focus all of them for people

Comment: I think the problem is related to some subtle setting in OpenCV.  I think this is configured differently on my install of the package on Windows and on the Pi.  I've looked through the camera settings and I don't see anything that looks like it would help.  The only setting that is close is changing Night Vision Mode from Auto to either Off or On.  I will try to do that for troubleshooting purposes, but I'd rather leave it on Auto as that is the best functionality.  My guess is that there is a timeout issue.  In the dark, I think the camera takes longer to acquire an image than in light...